# github clone (auto initialisation)

Tags: git, github, clone, init

Does github provide the option to have a repository auto initialised so that you can just do `git clone <uri>` rather than the entire init, add file, commit, add remote, push process as shown in their instructions?

If not, is there a technical reason as to why?

Running `git clone <uri>` after having the repository created by github seems a lot easier.

Comment: Of course! Those are just for you to learn a few things to do. Have you tried just writing `git clone uri` to see what happens? Or issue `git help clone`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `git clone <uri>` should work fine. There are several options, including the folder to create the clone in. The default is to create a folder whose name matches the source repo.

Check out the [git-clone man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-clone.html) for all of the gory details.

Comment: It does indeed work. I have to specify the branch name on the first push back to github (just `git push` doesn't work) but everything else is fine. It would be nice if github listed the URI at the bottom of the instructions for easy copy-paste though.